# Rows of date to columns of day-of-week

Tags: sql, date, pivot

I have a table and I have users with dates...

```
| Employee_Name | Date       |
| CG            | 2019-04-22 |
| CG            | 2019-04-26 |
| CG            | 2019-04-24 |
```

I am trying to get results so when I query and say `Date BETWEEN (@start AND @end)` it would give me results like:

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME | Monday     | Tuesday | Wednesday  | Thursday | Friday     | Saturday | Sunday |
CG            | 2019-04-22 | NULL    | 2019-04-24 | NULL     | 2019-04-26 | NULL     | NULL   |
```

I am at a loss scratching my head honestly - I know i may be able to do it with a pivot.

Comment: use correlated subquery

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, you were shown a large hint that suggested you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax between them varies. You chose to ignore that hint, which means you now have to sit and wait while we ask **What specific DBMS are you using?** in order to answer your question. So, **What specific DBMS are you using?** - please answer by making an [edit] to your post and adding a tag for that specific DBMS.

Comment: that and what happens when the date range contains more than 7 days... e.g. when there are 2 mondays.

Comment: @SalmanA I also thought that!!!

Answer (score 2):

The following should work (perfectly if @d2 - @d1 < 7 otherwise it'll display the first date for each weekday):

```
SELECT Employee_Name
     , MIN(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Date) = 'Sunday'    THEN Date END) AS Sunday
     , MIN(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Date) = 'Monday'    THEN Date END) AS Monday
     , MIN(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Date) = 'Tuesday'   THEN Date END) AS Tuesday
     , MIN(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Date) = 'Wednesday' THEN Date END) AS Wednesday
     , MIN(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Date) = 'Thursday'  THEN Date END) AS Thursday
     , MIN(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Date) = 'Friday'    THEN Date END) AS Friday
     , MIN(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Date) = 'Saturday'  THEN Date END) AS Saturday
FROM t
WHERE Date BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2
GROUP BY Employee_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Pivot solution.

I added more sample data (one more employee and two dates) to test it out:

```
declare @weekday table (weekday varchar(10))
insert into @weekday (weekday) values 
('Monday'),
('Tuesday'),
('Wednesday'),
('Thursday'),
('Friday'),
('Saturday'), 
('Sunday')

select p.employee_name,[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday],[Sunday]
from (
select t.employee_name,t.date,w.weekday from (
select *, datename(weekday,date) as weekday
from #test) t
right join @weekday w
on w.weekday = t.weekday) s
pivot
(max(date)
for weekday in ([Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday],[Sunday])
) as p
where p.employee_name is not null
```

**Please change the table_name accordingly. (I used #test)**

Test Result:

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a07dd7c078abd265b6a1197635975e37)